# codeigniter custom routes with i18n

Tags: codeigniter, internationalization

I implemented i18n to my ci app according to http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/179036/ but my custom routes are not working anymore.

```
/* custom routes */
// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(en|de)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
// '/en' and '/de' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|de)$'] = $route['default_controller'];

$route['register'] = 'auth/register';
$route['login'] = 'auth/login';
$route['logout'] = 'auth/logout';
```

'register', 'login' and 'logout' are not routed to auth/something. Any idea why? I am getting 404 error (when I open en/login it wants to use login controller instead of auth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route are executed in the order they appear in your `routes.php`. So when your try `en/login` it will reach the line which says `$route['^(en|de)/(.+)$'] = "$2";` and then route it to the controller `login`

You actually want to do 2 different re-routes.. (from `en/login` -> 'login' -> 'auth/login' ) thats why its failing.

You probably just need to add a special rules for auth stuff like this:

```
$route['^(en|de)/register'] = 'auth/register';
$route['^(en|de)/login'] = 'auth/login';
$route['^(en|de)/logout'] = 'auth/logout';
```

.. and make sure to put it **before** your generic i18n routes.

read [the online documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) for more information.

Comment: thank you, great! I have one more trouble - When I try to login on en/login after form submition it redirects me at de/page instead of en/page. Why it switch language from en to de? thanks in advance